# Regex valid AdresseEmail c#

Tags: c#, regex, email

i'm currently developping an application with , i have probleme with Regex.

i have a file txt that contain email like that:

```
test@test.uk
test1@test.uk
```

my function loademail must import email from txt and add him to list result.

but the probleme he still work he dont add any email

this is my code :

```
public class Loademail
    {
        public EmailAddress email;

        public List<Loademail> loademail()
        {
            var result = new List<Loademail>();
            string fileSocks = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "liste.txt"));
            var input = File.ReadAllText(fileSocks);
            var r = new Regex(@"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
     + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
     + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
     + @"([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,23})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
            {
                string Email = match.Groups[1].Value;
                Loademail bi = new Loademail();
                bi.email = EmailAddress.Parse(Email);
                result.Add(bi);
                //result.Add(Email);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

what i should do thnks?

Comment: On the surface, you have not told the compiler to ignore whitespace.

Comment: #sln what i should do for ignore whitespace

Comment: Posted the constant.

Comment: Probably you should use `string input = ..` and `Regex r = new Regex(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Use ignore pattern whitespace.

**Edit**

Try it using a `while () { next match ...}`

Like this

```
Match _mData = Rx.Match( Input );
while (_mData.Success)
{
    if (_mData.Groups[1].Success )
    Console.WriteLine("{0} \r\n", _mData.Groups[1].Value);
    _mData = _mData.NextMatch();
}
```

// -------------------

```
 Regex Rx = new Regex(
    @"
       ^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@((([0
       -1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{
       1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-
       5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][
       0-9])){1}|([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-
       Z0-9-]{1,23})$
       ",
       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace );
```

Use a good tool to format and process large expressions.

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ^ 
 (                                    # (1 start)
      ( [\w-]+ \. )+                       # (2)
      [\w-]+ 
   |  ( [a-zA-Z]{1} | [\w-]{2,} )          # (3)
 )                                    # (1 end)
 @
 (                                    # (4 start)
      (                                    # (5 start)
           (                                    # (6 start)
                [0-1]? [0-9]{1,2} 
             |  25 [0-5] 
             |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
           )                                    # (6 end)
           \.
           (                                    # (7 start)
                [0-1]? 
                [0-9]{1,2} 
             |  25 [0-5] 
             |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
           )                                    # (7 end)
           \.
           (                                    # (8 start)
                [0-1]? [0-9]{1,2} 
             |  25 [0-5] 
             |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
           )                                    # (8 end)
           \.
           (                                    # (9 start)
                [0-1]? 
                [0-9]{1,2} 
             |  25 [0-5] 
             |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
           )                                    # (9 end)
      ){1}                                 # (5 end)
   |  
      ( [a-zA-Z0-9]+ [\w-]+ \. )+          # (10)
      [a-zA-Z]{1} [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,23} 
 )                                    # (4 end)
 $
```

As a side note, this is a good email regex as well.

```
 # http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address
 # ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$     

 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
 @
 [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 )?
 (?:
      \. 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      (?:
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      )?
 )*
 $
```

Comment: she not work , i think problem in foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
        {

Comment: @FatiFleur - More likely its not matching. Updated a new way, use a `while() { }`. And probably use the email regex I posted from html5. Also, take out the anchors `^$` if the email is embedded in free text.

Comment: i test with while , when i debug i get _mData.Success is false i think problem in regex

Comment: @FatiFleur  - Well, like I said, take out the anchors `^$` and use the regex I posted at the bottom.

Comment: she not work  when i debug input give me the result like that test@orange.fr\r\ntest1@gmail.com